# Extracting all the tr tags data in table

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, find, html-table

HTML code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Supervisor</th><th>Room</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Anastasiou, Alexandros</td>
<td><a href="mailto:alexandros.anastasiou07">alexandros.anastasiou07</a></td>
<td>Prof Duff</td>
<td>512b</td>
<td>47838</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ashmore, Anthony</td>
<td><a href="mailto:a.ashmore12">a.ashmore12</a></td>
<td>Prof Waldram</td>
<td>512b</td>
<td>47838</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Banks, Elliot</td>
<td><a href="mailto:EB713">EB713</a></td>
<td>Prof Gauntlett</td>
<td>512a</td>
<td>47839</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Above is the html code. In this 3rd td tag of every tr contains further tags... Please help me out.

My python code:

```
    souphandler=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

    table=souphandler.find('table')
    tr_tag=table.find('tr')
    try:
        while(tr_tag is not None):
            for row in tr_tag:
                print(row.string)
            tr_tag=tr_tag.findNext('tr')
```

Here in this code it is printing everything repeatedly many times. I want to extract all the data in tr tags..

Comment: It would be much simpler to read if you just copy your code directly into the question...

Comment: just ignore the try: statement

Comment: I don't see anything remotely difficult in the table, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: It is printing the same result **11 times**. I really don't know why is this printing like this

Comment: please tell me some other way to do this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just find the tr tags and extract the th tags from the first and the  td tags from the rest:

```
h = """
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Supervisor</th><th>Room</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Anastasiou, Alexandros</td>
<td><a href="mailto:alexandros.anastasiou07">alexandros.anastasiou07</a></td>
<td>Prof Duff</td>
<td>512b</td>
<td>47838</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ashmore, Anthony</td>
<td><a href="mailto:a.ashmore12">a.ashmore12</a></td>
<td>Prof Waldram</td>
<td>512b</td>
<td>47838</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Banks, Elliot</td>
<td><a href="mailto:EB713">EB713</a></td>
<td>Prof Gauntlett</td>
<td>512a</td>
<td>47839</td>
</tr>
</table>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
table = soup.find("table")
print(",".join([th.text for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]))
for tr in table.select("tr + tr"):
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    print(tds[1].a["href"])
    print(", ".join([td.text for td in tds]))
```

Which would give you:

```
Name,Email,Supervisor,Room,Phone
mailto:alexandros.anastasiou07
Anastasiou, Alexandros, alexandros.anastasiou07, Prof Duff, 512b, 47838
mailto:a.ashmore12
Ashmore, Anthony, a.ashmore12, Prof Waldram, 512b, 47838
mailto:EB713
Banks, Elliot, EB713, Prof Gauntlett, 512a, 47839
```

Comment: what does this table.select("tr +tr") do..is it equivalent to table.select("tr")?

Comment: It takes all the tr tags after the first